# i have some gradle issues... it is showing some error message

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> execution failed for task:app-merge debug resources.  Some file crunching failed.

this is the message shown

these i have used

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'


}
```

Comment: Are you using same versions of `appcompat-v7` and `design`?

Answer (score 0):

You problem seems to be because of the import of different versions of `appcompat-v7` and `design`.

Update the gradle import of `design` to version 23.2.1, like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```